# Is "can best be" proper English?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence proper English?

*"X can best be defined as Y"*

And if so, can it be used in academic writing?

Comment: No, it's not proper english, which is the spin you put on a ball in billiards. If you put "can best be" on a ball in billiards, nothing much will come of it. As to English, a Germanic language, yes, "can best be" is English alright. There's 11000000 hits for it on Google, for starters. Including academic writing. (There's only 600 hits for "an orange Cadillac". None of them in academic writing for all I can see.) You will need to specify what exactly rubs you the wrong way about such a common turn of phrase, then we can address the actual problem you're actually having. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback. I'm sorry I've ruined your day by (apparently) asking such a dumb, poorly articulated question.

Comment: Hi, Kas S, and thanks for your interest in English language and usage. I think RegDwigнt was simply having a little joke at your expense based on the fact that _english_ with a lowercase _e_ has a narrow (and not especially language- or nationality-related) meaning, whereas _English_ with a capital _E_ does have language- and nationality-related meanings. In any event, it may be best in this case just to smile a bit uncertainly and nod your head and carry on. And most of all, don't let his answer ruin **your** day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**can best be** versus **can be best**

**Can be best** is more used by about four to one.  [textranch.com](https://textranch.com/41026/can-be-best/or/can-best-be/)

As in:

X can best be assisted by a trained ...

X can be best assisted by a trained ...

You can use either but the 'can be best', to my sense, is better. I doubt much if any notice will be made in spoken English using either! In academics, I would go with the majority.

Comment: Not sure if it's cultural, but to my American ear "can best be" sounds better, and [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+best+be%2Ccan+be+best&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20best%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20be%20best%3B%2Cc0) seems to agree that it's the more popular usage.